# Leer un array bidimensional (matriz) mediante scanf

Tags: c, stdin

He probado el siguiente código:

```
scanf("%d %d",&N,&M);

int matrix[N][M];

for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<M;M++){
        scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
    }
}
```

pero al ejecutarlo no me deja de pedir datos, el programa no avanza.

Comment: ¿que valores le pones al primer scanf? ej. si pones 100 100 .. te pedira 10000 datos.. ademas pones printf en el titulo pero no lo usas en el codigo. Puede explicar el objetivo y el problema? salu2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En no todas las versiones de C se puede asignar el espacio a la matriz de esa manera, para hacerlo dinámicamente debes usar `malloc`:

```
int* matrix; 
int n,m;
scanf("%d", &n);
scanf("%d", &m);
matrix = malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));
```

Ademas en tu código en el for interno el paso de incremento lo estás haciendo con M++, y consecuentemente, nunca cumple la condición de corte, y se queda ciclando ahí. Deberías reemplazarlo con j++

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
        scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Quizás recuerdas bien cuando lo aprendiste, pero desde 1999 (C99) en adelante esta permitido hacerlo.

Comment: Marcelo, para futuras referencias lo que comentas en la nota es conocido como "*Arreglo de Longitud Variable*" o Variable Length Array (VLA) en Inglés.